# How do I print a specific number of input statements in a loop?

Tags: python, loops

I'm writing a code for my class but I'm having a little trouble at one part. I'm having the user input a number and then I need a loop to print specific statements based off the number the user inputted. So for example:

```
def main():
    totalnumber = input("Enter the number of circles: ")
    i = 0
    for i in totalnumber:
        i = 0 + 1
        value = input("Enter the radius of circle",str(i)+":")
```

So I basically need the output to look like:

```
Enter the number of circles: 3
Enter the radius of circle 1:
Enter the radius of circle 2:
Enter the radius of circle 3:
```

I'm getting the error

```
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

Is what I'm doing above okay to do or should I use a different approach?
If its okay what is wrong within my code that would be giving me that sort of error?

Comment: replace comma with plus sign: `"Enter the radius of circle"+str(i)+":"`

Comment: You got a `,` inside input

Comment: You're using a comma. That doesn't do string concatenation. You either want `+` or `.format`. There's some other issues here, like that you aren't storing the radii anywhere, so you're just overwriting it every time you loop.

Comment: Oh wow didn't even notice the comma and yes I noticed that the radii isn't being stored anywhere which I fixed in my actual code. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def main():
    total_number = input("Enter the number of circles: ")
    for number in range(1, int(total_number) + 1):
        value = input("Enter the radius of circle {}: ".format(number))

main()
```

First: you need to convert the input to `int`, then iterate it by the number.

Notes:

- use python [pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) when naming your parameters user `_` between the names
- string formating is best with [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) try to use it.

Comment: This worked exactly how I needed it to. Thank you for the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop doesn't look correct.
Try

```
for number in range(int(totalnumber)):
    i = number+1
    value = input("Enter the radius of circle"+str(i)+":")
```

Comment: `totalnumber` is an `str` object you cannot use it with `range`